# Why I receive no answer from an ARP request?

Tags: ethernet, arp

I'm working on an embedded device that connects on local network with RJ45 and when the system sends an ARP request to know the mac address of the gateway, no answer at all.

If I clear the arp table on my Windows, the Windows asks exactly the same ARP request and got an answer!

I sniffed the packet and the only difference inside the request packet is a 0 trailer on the embedded device at the end of the packet and that the target mac address is ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff where the windows one is 00:00:00:00:00:00 (wikipedia seems to say that it should be ffffffffff)

I tried to changed the mac address in case my gateway banned the mac due to arp spam but it doesn't change anything. I also try with DHCP IP and static IP, same problem...

Windows packet:

```
Frame 1 (42 bytes on wire, 42 bytes captured)
     Frame is marked: False
     Arrival Time: Jan 29, 2010 12:05:49.775534000
     Time delta from previous packet: -77.580549000 seconds
     Time since reference or first frame: 6354.738379000 seconds
     Frame Number: 1
     Packet Length: 42 bytes
     Capture Length: 42 bytes
     Protocols in frame: eth:arp
Ethernet II, Src: 00:1e:8c:b5:d0:00, Dst: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
     Type: ARP (0x0806)

Address Resolution Protocol (request)
     Hardware type: Ethernet (0x0001)
     Protocol type: IP (0x0800)
     Hardware size: 6
     Protocol size: 4
     Opcode: request (0x0001)
     Sender MAC address: 00:1e:8c:b5:d0:00 (00:1e:8c:b5:d0:00)
     Sender IP address: 192.168.0.14 (192.168.0.14)
     Target MAC address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)
     Target IP address: 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)

0000:  FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 1E 8C B5 D0 00 08 06 00 01  ................
0010:  08 00 06 04 00 01 00 1E 8C B5 D0 00 C0 A8 00 0E  ................
0020:  00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 A8 00 01                    ..........
```

Embedded device packet:

```
Frame 1 (60 bytes on wire, 60 bytes captured)
     Frame is marked: False
     Arrival Time: Jan 29, 2010 12:07:04.257748000
     Time delta from previous packet: -3.098335000 seconds
     Time since reference or first frame: 6429.220593000 seconds
     Frame Number: 1
     Packet Length: 60 bytes
     Capture Length: 60 bytes
     Protocols in frame: eth:arp
Ethernet II, Src: 00:04:a3:12:34:05, Dst: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
     Type: ARP (0x0806)
     Trailer: 000000000000000000000000000000000000
Address Resolution Protocol (request)
     Hardware type: Ethernet (0x0001)
     Protocol type: IP (0x0800)
     Hardware size: 6
     Protocol size: 4
     Opcode: request (0x0001)
     Sender MAC address: 00:04:a3:12:34:05 (00:04:a3:12:34:05)
     Sender IP address: 192.168.0.129 (192.168.0.129)
     Target MAC address: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
     Target IP address: 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)

0000:  FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 04 A3 12 34 05 08 06 00 01  ..........4.....
0010:  08 00 06 04 00 01 00 04 A3 12 34 05 C0 A8 00 81  ..........4.....
0020:  FF FF FF FF FF FF C0 A8 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0030:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00              ............
```

Comment: Are you sure your network does not utilize vlan or something similar(tunneling?) ? Your windows packet is less than 64 bytes which is the minimum length of an ethernet frame includeing the crc. Some nics/drivers will strip off such a layer and you wont see it in wireshark.

Comment: No vlan. It's just an internet box (freebox) with my pc and embeded on the box with rj45 on the box (that act as a router)
Since I sniff on the same PC, perhaps wireshark (packetyzer in fact) remove the trailer.

Comment: I also have some very strange behaviors like:

- when my computer ping the pic, it works 2 times and after it timesouts (the LED still continues to blink every seconds)
- when it tries to get an IP with DHCP, it asks N times (where N is random), get the answer from gateway, send the request, receive the ACK but doesn't validate the DHCP and asks another time...

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, It was a problem with the TX where the polarity was inverted and cause these problems.

I inverted the polarity and now it works perfectly.